# how to read json configuration from application.properties using spring boot ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java

I want to read the application properties using class in spring boot 2.6.6, the configuration of application properties look like this:

```
dolphin.api.custom-access-token-expire-time={"FORTUNE":60000}
```

the configuration read class look like this:

```
package com.dolphin.soa.post.config.common;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dolphin.api")
public class AppCommonConfig {

    private Map<String,Long> customAccessTokenExpireTime;

}
```

but this could not work, how to map the application.properties to the class? this is the error output:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[19:19:43:537] [ERROR] - org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.report(LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java:40) - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'dolphin.api.custom-access-token-expire-time' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Long>:

    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Long>]
```

Comment: 1. Did you scan/`@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppCommonConfig.class)` on using class? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types 2. Why `@Component`?

Comment: I have already configure the scan: `@EnableConfigurationProperties({CruiseRedisKeysConfig.class, AppCommonConfig.class})`. @xerx593

Comment: Cool! (Still `@Component` is strange/off documentation) ..so the problem seems to be "naming"!? ("Relaxed binding" chapter & table in above link.)

Comment: Is it too much effort to change to `...token-expire-time` ? (`-`s instead of (last) `.`s)

Comment: ..alternatively: you can/must structure your config "deeper"..

Comment: #Latest update: It looks not possible to use json /yaml inside properties... Try with `...expire-time.FORTUNE=6000` (and `Map<String, ?>`?) like documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.maps) alternatively: use yaml